Finding the trajectories of fluid particles

I have completed the question up to when it asks me to show that up to leading order, the trajectories of fluid particles for these waves are ellipses. I am slightly confused what I am looking for; finding $u, v$ seem unfeasible since they are functions of $x,y$ and $t$ (although it does then later ask me to sketch the fluid velocity). Any help would be appreciated as I'm unsure where to start.
